# how to increment every loop

Tags: loops, robotframework, increment

lets say i have a 5 set of values for first name and last name, i want 1 set per loop in a increment way, how can i do that? p.s im not a programmer xD so dont expect some proggy things

```
@{item1}    create list     a   b   c
@{item2}    create list     d   e   f
@{count}    create list     0   1   2


:for    ${i}    in range    1   5

\   log to console      @{item1}[0], @{item2}[0]
```

a, d

a, d

a, d

a, d

test                                                                  | PASS |

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build a list for the index:

```
    @{item1}    create list     a   b   c
    @{item2}    create list     d   e   f

    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    3
    \    log to console  @{item1}[${i}], @{item2}[${i}]
```